# Running multiple versions of Maven and JDK on Windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, version

In my work I use an older version of Maven (3.0.2) to build my Java 1.7 application. This cannot be changed.

But I would like to install and use for other projects on same computer (Windows) newer versions of Maven and Java. Is it possible? What should I do in order to manage multiple versions of Maven and Java in Windows?

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at https://sdkman.io Apart from that I really ask why such an ancient version of Maven can not be changed because 3.0.2 is more than 10 years old...

Comment: You can just unpack a new version of Maven and of Java. You can then configure them in your IDE. BTW: Maven is pretty stable and compiling with Maven 3.8.2 instead of 3.0.2 should not make a difference.

Comment: For the Maven version you should consider switching to [Maven Wrapper](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-wrapper-plugin/usage.html) which allows you to have a specific version for each project without requiring the developer to have that specific version installed. This kind of setup is already the default in Gradle and works very well.

Comment: Also, I agree with the other commenters: you should really try to upgrade Maven on those ancient projects. **At least** upgrade to the latest 3.0 release (which is 3.0.5 now and will probably always be that version), but ideally to [a non-EOLed version](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) (i.e. 3.1 or up).

Comment: @JoachimSauer The Maven Wrapper which you have linked does only work for Maven 4.X but NOT for Maven 3.X For Maven 3.X you have to use https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper